# How to start master flow activity via intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, master-detail

I try to start my master detail flow activity,via intent.But my app crashes. What should I do? Need help.Please.

Here is my Code:

```
package com.example.baymax.farmax;    

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;    
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;    
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;    
import android.view.View;    

public class Propergrowth extends AppCompatActivity {    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_propergrowth);
}
    public void cher(View view) {    
        startActivity(new Intent(Propergrowth.this,CropsListActivity.class));
    }
public void Kha(View view) {
        Intent ch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(ch);    
    }    
}        
}
```

Whenever I try to open the Master Flow activity, by clicking the button, the app crashes, I tried many alternatives for the way of using intents, But though it crashes. Please, Need help.

Comment: Please Help.. I am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

`public void Kha(View view) {
        Intent ch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(ch);

    }`

try this

`public void Kha(View view) {
        Intent ch = new Intent(Propergrowth.this, MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(ch);

    }`

hopefully this will hep you

Comment: what is main activity in Master detail flow

Comment: I have used the dummy content class to add items in the list, but i have used 17 items, Is this a problem

Comment: i did not understand your question! can u edit your post with your master detail flow file(Activity) so i can have a better look at it

Comment: I want to run this app on API 10, gingerbread. and therefore i have declared API 10 as the minsdkVersion

Comment: okay! that detail is irrelevant. can u just post the main code of master detail flow.

Comment: please tell me the necessary changes

Comment: So that I would be able to run this on gingerbread, without any crashes. Is it safe to add 17 items to the Dummy Content java class, Please take a look even on that,  I will be very glad if i seek help.